# Trocar valor de duas variáveis sem usar uma terceira, usando apenas soma ou subtração

Tags: c, lógica

Utilizando apenas duas variáveis (A e B) e utilizando também apenas (soma ou subtração), fazer com que o valor de A virasse o valor de B e o valor de B se tornasse o valor de A.

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser usando o operador ou-exclusivo? Se sim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 123;
    int b = 456;
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
    a ^= b;
    b ^= a;
    a ^= b;
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
123 456
456 123
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/M3yc2U)